# How to turn off the automatic gesture to go back a view with a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

So I'm noticing all of my views are receiving the gesture to go back (pop a view) when the user swipes on the very left side of the screen (in either orientation) (**This is new with iOS7**)

I've tried so far with no avail to turn it off using:

```
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Within the init of the NavigationController itself (as the delegate seems to be using that).

Comment: None of the answers work for iOS 8

Comment: @sole007 See my answer below.. worked for me

Answer (score 72, accepted):

#### obj-c

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

#### swift

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: Yeah!! That works. It only works though in the AppDelegate after I create the NavigationController though. I tried in the init and load of my implementation of the NavigationController with no success.

Comment: what do you mean by *tried in the init and load of my implementation of the NavigationController*?

Comment: In my NavigationController (subclass of UINavigationController): I tried this in the "- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {"
Added: `super.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
  self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;`

Comment: I'd try implementing `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:` and `initWithRootViewController:` which are the two init methods defined by `UINavigationController`

Comment: @Rajesh I finally found time to look into this, and I came up with a workaround. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround. Works on official iOS 8 like a charm.

Comment: This isn't working, the line: self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self, comes back with an error that it doesn't conform to protocol. I'm assuming the protocol requires that function above, but it's not resolving the error. I'm putting it in viewDidLoad() on the vc I need to disable it on.

Comment: I fixed the above but still this isn't working, I have UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in the class references. I have the self.navigationController?.interactivePop... line in the viewDidLoad(), I have the function down in the main body of the viewcontroller. I get no errors, but what am I doing wrong?  It also needs an optional question mark there as you can see.

Comment: it seems `enabled` is now `isEnabled`

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Gabriele's Solution.

To support any iOS before iOS 7 you will need to wrap this code with this:

```
if([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
```

This will stop the App crashing in iOS 6 and iOS 5 for missing selector.

Answer (score 5):

I use this solution in my project, it disables only interactivePopGestureRecognizer and allows you to use another gesture recognizers.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {

        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

    }

}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if ([gestureRecognizer isEqual:self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer]) {

        return NO;

    } else {

        return YES;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found out setting the gesture to disabled only doesn't always work. It does work, but for me it only did after I once used the backgesture. Second time it wouldn't trigger the backgesture.

Fix for me was to delegate the gesture and implement the shouldbegin method to return NO:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Disable iOS 7 back gesture
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Enable iOS 7 back gesture
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For IOS 8 (Swift):

```
class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Comment: @PhilHudson show some code. Did you set the NavigationController in the interface builder to the custom one?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for previous than iOS 7

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```