# Why is my navigation view popping?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, xcode6, tableview

I've a problem, when I'm scrolling up and down in the table view highlighted in the view below it can be fine for a few scrolls up and down and then seemingly randomly it pops back to the view before (but doesn't update the screen so it just looks stuck in the table view) Sometimes on the first scroll it pops the view too.

[image: storyboard]
I don't really want to post my whole class unless someone thinks it's necessary but I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction as to why this would be happening.

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSLog(@"Is this being dismissed: %d", [self isBeingDismissed]); // returns 0
NSLog(@"isMovingFromParentViewController %d", [self isMovingFromParentViewController]); // returns 0
NSLog(@"viewWillDisappear occured on bookmark table"); 
}

-(void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
NSLog(@"This VC has has been pushed popped OR covered"); // this is happening
if (!parent)
    NSLog(@"This happens ONLY when it's popped"); // this is happening
}
```

Could anyone tell me a way to find out what is calling the willMoveToParentViewController or viewWillDisappear? I've had a look in the debug log with a pause but it just says before

A breakpoint on willMoveToParentViewController shows this in Thread 1

```
 0 [bookmarkTableViewController willMoveToParentViewController:]
 1 _popViewControllerNormal
```

A breakpoint on viewWillDisappear

```
 0 [bookmarkTableViewController viewWillDisappear:]
 1 [UIViewController _setViewApppearState:isAnimating:]
```

So as summary, I can use it fine for 10 scrolls up or down and then it happens, or maybe it will happen on the first scroll so it looks random to me. If anyone thinks it'll help me sharing my entire class it'll help but it's pretty much just a generic table view.

EDIT

I've found that it's something to do with the segue.

When I segue with just 'Show (e.g Push)', it lets me have the navigation back button but crashes. When I do 'Show Detail (e.g replace)', it never crashes which leads me to think I could just fake the navigation back button but really i'd like to know why this is happening.

EDIT 2:

I've noticed that the problem occurs even with a blank table list so it has nothing to do with that. When I spam scrolling up and down on the totally empty new table view controller it does the exact same thing.

[image]

For some reason scrolling up and down in scroll area eventually locks the tableview UI and calls the previous view controllers viewwillappear

EDIT 3:

I think it might have something to do with the navigation controller, I just stripped hte project to its bare bones and i noticed sometimes instead of table scrolling it's doing the side-swiping navigation back gesture thing

EDIT 4:

Yep it was that, I can't even fix it apparently with objective-c as of yet it says https://stackoverflow.com/a/19019924/4056064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. this navigation gesture turn off thing doesn't work so occasionally a back navigation sweep was detected rather than a scroll and it called my previous view and then returned it to the current one. source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19019924/4056064   happy to hear if anyone has any work arounds that.

Edit: found a work around

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
return NO;
}

if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
}
```